# How does HTTP redirect work with HTTP methods?

Tags: http, http-status-code-301, http-status-codes, http-redirect, http-response-codes

I read the [HTTP response status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#status.3xx), [location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-10.2.2) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) documentation, what I could understand was that:

**Permanent**:

- `301`: Permanent redirect

  - **Accepted request method**: All HTTP methods
  - **Recommended request method**: `GET` `HEAD`
  - **Redirect method**: Must be changed to `GET`
- `308`: Permanent redirect

  - **Accepted request method**: All HTTP methods
  - **Recommended application method**: Any
  - **Redirect method**: Preserve the request method

**Temporary**

- `302`: Temporary redirect

  - **Accepted request method**: All HTTP methods
  - **Recommended request method**: `GET` `HEAD`
  - **Redirect method**: Must be changed to `GET`
- `307`: Temporary redirect

  - **Accepted request method**: All HTTP methods
  - **Recommended application method**: Any
  - **Redirect method**: Preserve the request method
- `303`: See other

  - **Accepted request method**: All HTTP methods
  - **Recommended request method**:`POST` `PUT`
  - **Request redirection method**: Must be changed to `GET`

This behavior is due to [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-15.4-3.1) and [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-15.4-6.4.1), I quote:

> ...Prevailing practice eventually converged on changing the method to GET...

> 4. Change the request method according to the redirecting status code's semantics, if applicable.

**First question**: Is this correct?

But what does point 5 mean?

> If the request method has been changed to GET or HEAD, remove...

I now know that HTTP status codes `301`, `302` and `303` redirect is changed to the `GET` method, but...

**Second question** in which case is it changed to a `HEAD` method (For exmaple, from `POST` to `HEAD`, `PUT` to `HEAD`, etc.)?

**Third question**: Is there a way that the client (may be a browser or other user agent) can redirect from a `GET` to `POST`, or a `DELETE` to `GET`, etc.? I ask this to see what the limit of this is or simply, is this incoherent to do?